# Delete from database where one part of a two part primary key has duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

This question stumps me.  I have a database with a table that has a primary key that consists of two fields.  In the end I require that the primary key only be one field, but I need to delete the duplicate entries from the table.

In other words the table has:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`field1`, `field2`)
```

There are entries that have duplicate field1 and different field2. So I have entries like this:

```
field1 | field2
1 | 1
1 | 2
2 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 1
4 | 1
```

I want to delete 1 of each of those entries that have duplicates on field1.

How can I do this with MySQL / SQL?

Comment: which entry would you like to delete in case of duplicates? Is it the new entry or the old entry that your looking to delete?

Comment: The second field is not a time but a filename.  Just duplicates that ended up in both files.

Comment: But, it's OK if I delete either the first or second record.

Comment: Try our my solution then

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work in your case,

```
DELETE t1 FROM table t1 
INNER JOIN table t2 
WHERE t1.id > t2.id 
AND t1.field1 = t2.field1
```

> In this query I am joining the same table and picking duplicate values of `field1` with different id and removing those.

Hope this works!!

Comment: The problem with your solution is that both fields are in the same table, so I don't need the join.

Comment: You need join to get those duplicates and remove them or you can try a nested query to do the same

Comment: @jonnyjandles you can use windowing functions

Comment: I only have one table, so your example would have to join t1 to t1.  But even then I can't see how that solution would work.  Also, you can't `DELETE t1 FROM t1'.  The syntax is wrong.  SQL is `DELETE FROM t1`.

Comment: Have you tried running the query in console? I have tried the same query and it works fine for me. @jonnyjandles

Comment: How could I possibly run the query?  I don't have two tables.  Your query joins two tables.

Comment: You need to join the same table t1

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how the `delete from table` needs to be specified in the mysql syntax but essentially you are trying to remove the second entry for the field1 for each of its unique value. So in some way if you are able to retrieve those records and pass them as `select statements` under your `delete from table` clause it should work.

For instance, here is the query that would select 2nd row for each value of field1 if it is repeated

```
select field1, field2
from
(
select *, count(*) over (partition by field1) as ct 
, rank() over (partition by field1 order by field2 desc) as rn
from temp
) where rn = 1 and ct = 2
```

In your case it would return below records

```
field1  field2  
1         2
2         2
```

So then all you need to do is have a `delete from table` clause at the top of that `select` statement.

NOTE - I have tried a solution without a `join` and hence I maintain these 2 analytical functions.

For instance this works in something like BigQuery -

```
delete from TABLE where concat(field1, field2) in
(
select concat(field1, field2)
from
(
select *, count(*) over (partition by field1) as ct 
, rank() over (partition by field1 order by field2 desc) as rn
from TABLE 
) where rn = 1 and ct = 2
)
```